# Selecting records with latest year using data.table in R

Tags: r, select, filter, datatable

I have a datatable where the same entity appears more than one time with a different date.

My objective is to retain a single record for each entity, the one with the latest date.

My code is not right though.  For a reproducible example see below:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars
mtcars$model <- row.names(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)
mtcars[, year := 2000]
mtcars1 <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), 5) , ]
mtcars1[, year := 2001]
mtcars2 <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), 5) , ]
mtcars2[, year := 2002]
mtcars <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars1, mtcars2)
setDT(mtcars)
mtcars

mtcars_latest <- mtcars[year == max(year) , names(mtcars), with = FALSE , by = model]
```

With the last line I intend to group by model and then within each group select the record with the latest year (`year == max(year)`).  Moreover, I want all the variables (columns) of the original datatable to be returned, so I put names(mtcars), with = FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is what you are looking for :

```
library(data.table)

mtcars[, names(mtcars), with = FALSE, by = .(model, max(year))]

> mtcars[, names(mtcars), with = FALSE, by = .(model, max(year))]
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb               model year
 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4           Mazda RX4 2000
 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4       Mazda RX4 Wag 2000
 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1          Datsun 710 2000
 4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      Hornet 4 Drive 2000
 5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   Hornet Sportabout 2000
 6: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1             Valiant 2000
 7: 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4          Duster 360 2000
 8: 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2           Merc 240D 2000
 9: 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2            Merc 230 2000
10: 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4            Merc 280 2000
11: 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4           Merc 280C 2000
12: 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3          Merc 450SE 2000
13: 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3          Merc 450SL 2000
14: 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3         Merc 450SLC 2000
15: 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4  Cadillac Fleetwood 2000
16: 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 Lincoln Continental 2000
17: 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4   Chrysler Imperial 2000
18: 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1            Fiat 128 2000
19: 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2         Honda Civic 2000
20: 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1      Toyota Corolla 2000
21: 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1       Toyota Corona 2000
22: 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2    Dodge Challenger 2000
23: 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2         AMC Javelin 2000
24: 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4          Camaro Z28 2000
25: 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2    Pontiac Firebird 2000
26: 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1           Fiat X1-9 2000
27: 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2       Porsche 914-2 2000
28: 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2        Lotus Europa 2000
29: 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4      Ford Pantera L 2000
30: 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6        Ferrari Dino 2000
31: 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8       Maserati Bora 2000
32: 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2          Volvo 142E 2000
33: 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2          Volvo 142E 2001
34: 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1           Fiat X1-9 2001
35: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   Hornet Sportabout 2001
36: 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3          Merc 450SL 2001
37: 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4   Chrysler Imperial 2001
38: 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4      Ford Pantera L 2002
39: 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3         Merc 450SLC 2002
40: 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2         AMC Javelin 2002
41: 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2    Dodge Challenger 2002
42: 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4            Merc 280 2002
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` offers an excellent interface for such operations:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars_latest=  
  copy(mtcars) %>% 
  group_by(model) %>% # For each model
  arrange(year) %>%   # Sort by year
  filter(row_number()==n())  # And take the last row
```